# How to calculate the volatility matrix with multiple stocks

Tags: volatility, programming, matlab

calculating the volatility for a single stock is straightforward. However, I'm not sure whether my approach for calculating the volatility matrix for multiple stocks is correct:

I assume a log-normal distribution of the stock prices. Therefore I calculate the log returns, calculate the variance-covariance matrix of the log returns and perform the cholesky decomposition of the variance-covariance matrix. The result from the last step is, as far as I am aware of, the volatility matrix.

Let ln_sec be a m x n matrix with the log returns of n securities over a period of m months, then my matlab code is as follows:

```
vcm = cov(ln_sec) %var-cov matrix
vcm = vcm * 12 %annualize var-cov matrix
vm = chol(vcm) %volatility matrix
```

Would you agree on my approach?

Thank you.

Edit: I forgot to mention the application in order to discuss a suitable solution. The volatility matrix is used to calculate a market price of risk vector as follows

```
(drift - risk-free-rate*1)/vm
```

where drift is a n x 1 vector with the mean drift rates of n assets and 1 is a n x 1 vector with 1's.
The market price of risk vector is then used to simulate a state-price density (pricing kernel).

Answer (score 1):

You can just take the diagonal of the var-cov matrix. This should give you the variance of each stock and then take sqrt of that for std. deviation.

```
sd = sqrt(diag(vcm))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm struggling with your solution because I would disregard the correlation between the assets...

Comment: Then it depends completely on the application of why are you doing this in the first place. I assumed you are looking at stocks individually. Can you elaborate what will you be using this for? Sometimes application derives what approach to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach based perhaps on [The Complex Unit's forum post](https://www.quantnet.com/threads/computing-market-price-of-risk-for-more-than-one-risky-asset.17675/) is correct.  However, you may be making this more confusing for yourself with the notation and vocabulary.

The phrase volatility matrix is not really correct though I can see how someone might get there because the market price of risk formula looks like and is related to the [Sharpe Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharpe_ratio) formula.  A [Cholesky Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) is mainly a tool for solving inverse matrix problems.  In this case the inverse problem is what would the market price need to be to justify holding this return stream as mean-variance optimized portfolio.

Does that help clarify?

Comment: Also, you might want to write the inverse of vm instead of division by vm so it is clear that you need the inverse of a matrix (done via Cholesky Decomposition) rather than a single volatility value.